# Compiler giving error: format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]

Tags: c++

I wrote a `scanf("%f"), x` (`x` is a `float`). And the compiler gives the error that is on the title. Both `%f` and `%e` are giving the same result.

Comment: `scanf()` is from C, so it does not support references. Because of that you have to pass pointers to allow function to modify your variables. But you better use `std::cin` in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must address the floating point variable with an ampersand to tell the compiler it's being stored in the memory.

You've done:

```
scanf("%f", x); // will obviously throw you a fatal warning
```

Consider:

```
scanf("%f", &x); // correct statement
```

That's it.

Comment: What do you mean by that exception?

Comment: That exception doesn't requires to address with an ampersand.

Comment: Again what exception do you mean? If you need to enter value into a `char` variable by scanf()? Or what?

Comment: Yeah, if you need to enter a char variable by scanf(), you don't need and that's what I was talking about by "exception".

Comment: Then you are wrong with that "exception".